# Resolve oltu openid connect dependency in maven

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, pom.xml, oltu

This is not a question but a simple maven dependency solution of oltu openid connect that I like to share. I found it might be helpful to other as there's not too many resource about it on the web.

I was having a problem with oltu openid connect dependency in maven (pom). Somehow I found its groupid, artifact, and its version. But whenever I insert the dependency in pom, eclipse notifies me with missing artifact. The problem seemed like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as above mentioned that the dependency was not available in maven central repository. As I searched through web, I found those dependencies are hosted in other repository which is http://repository.idega.com/maven2/. After that, the solution was just to include this repository in your pom like shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Apache Snapshot Repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```